# Compile HTML in Angular 6

Tags: angular

Compile service response's html in angular 4+ and integrate in template.

We are using angular for front end and rest api services in backend, That service returns us  an html table with click,dblclick functions added to some attributes. 
Requirement:
We send a request to service, service returns html table with functions added. (those functions are defined in angular .ts file. )
we integrate the received html in template's html and the click functions should work.

Solutions considered so far: 
- Using $Compile was an option but it is not available after angular 2
- Using JIT with AOT Compiler but i have read that JIT compiler wouldn't make a production build. 
- A workaround which is working now is: (we loop through all html elements and bind the functions to this scope in that loop)

Is there any other suitable,less messy approach for all this?

**template.html**

```
<div id = "maintwo"></div>
```

**template-component.ts**:

```
ngOnInit() { 
     document.querySelector('#maintwo').innerHTML = decodeURIComponent("<table cellspacing=\"0\" class=\"x-panel-body x-grid-body x-panel-body-default x-box-layout-ct x-panel-body-default x-pivot-table\">\r\n\t<thead>\r\n\t\t<tr class=\"generic-row-style   even-row\">\r\n\t\t\t<th class=\"x-column-header-inner x-column-header x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable x-grid-header-ct x-docked x-grid-header-ct-default x-docked-top x-grid-header-ct-docked-top x-grid-header-ct-default-docked-top x-box-layout-ct x-docked-noborder-top x-docked-noborder-right x-docked-noborder-left x-pivot-header\">\r\n\t\t\t\t&nbsp;\r\n\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t<th class=\"x-column-header-inner x-column-header x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable x-grid-header-ct x-docked x-grid-header-ct-default x-docked-top x-grid-header-ct-docked-top x-grid-header-ct-default-docked-top x-box-layout-ct x-docked-noborder-top x-docked-noborder-right x-docked-noborder-left x-pivot-header\" ondblclick=\"javascript:Sbi.olap.eventManager.setCalculatedFieldParent('[Measures].[Amount processed]','0')\">\r\n\t\t\t\tAmount processed\r\n\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t<th class=\"x-column-header-inner x-column-header x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable x-grid-header-ct x-docked x-grid-header-ct-default x-docked-top x-grid-header-ct-docked-top x-grid-header-ct-default-docked-top x-box-layout-ct x-docked-noborder-top x-docked-noborder-right x-docked-noborder-left x-pivot-header\" ondblclick=\"javascript:Sbi.olap.eventManager.setCalculatedFieldParent('[Measures].[Amount requested]','0')\">\r\n\t\t\t\tAmount requested\r\n\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t<th class=\"x-column-header-inner x-column-header x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable x-grid-header-ct x-docked x-grid-header-ct-default x-docked-top x-grid-header-ct-docked-top x-grid-header-ct-default-docked-top x-box-layout-ct x-docked-noborder-top x-docked-noborder-right x-docked-noborder-left x-pivot-header\" ondblclick=\"javascript:Sbi.olap.eventManager.setCalculatedFieldParent('[Measures].[Query CM]','0')\">\r\n\t\t\t\tQuery CM\r\n\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t</tr>\r\n\t</thead>\r\n\t<tbody>\r\n\t\t<tr class=\"generic-row-style   even-row\">\r\n\t\t\t<th class=\"x-column-header-inner x-column-header x-column-header-align-left x-box-item x-column-header-default x-unselectable x-grid-header-ct x-docked x-grid-header-ct-default x-docked-top x-grid-header-ct-docked-top x-grid-header-ct-default-docked-top x-box-layout-ct x-docked-noborder-top x-docked-noborder-right x-docked-noborder-left x-pivot-header collapsed\" ondblclick=\"javascript:Sbi.olap.eventManager.setCalculatedFieldParent('[Dim date.All Dim date].[All Dim date]','1')\" style=\"padding-left: 0px;\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<img onclick=\"myFunction()\" src=\"../img/plus.gif\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\tAll Dim date\r\n\t\t\t\t</th>\r\n\t\t\t\t<td id=\"0!1!1!706\" class=\"x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1014 x-unselectable x-grid-cell-inner  x-grid-row-alt x-grid-data-row x-grid-with-col-lines x-grid-cell x-pivot-cell  even-column\" ondblclick=\"javascript:Sbi.olap.eventManager.makeEditable('0!1!1!706','Amount processed')\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t417\r\n\t\t\t\t</td>\r\n\t\t\t\t<td id=\"1!1!2!729\" class=\"x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1014 x-unselectable x-grid-cell-inner  x-grid-row-alt x-grid-data-row x-grid-with-col-lines x-grid-cell x-pivot-cell  odd-column\" ondblclick=\"javascript:Sbi.olap.eventManager.makeEditable('1!1!2!729','Amount requested')\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t48\r\n\t\t\t\t</td>\r\n\t\t\t\t<td id=\"2!1!3!736\" class=\"x-grid-cell x-grid-td x-grid-cell-gridcolumn-1014 x-unselectable x-grid-cell-inner  x-grid-row-alt x-grid-data-row x-grid-with-col-lines x-grid-cell x-pivot-cell  even-column\" ondblclick=\"javascript:Sbi.olap.eventManager.makeEditable('2!1!3!736','Query CM')\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t517\r\n\t\t\t\t</td>\r\n\t\t\t</tr>\r\n\t\t</tbody>\r\n\t</table>\r\n");        
}


myFunction(stringx){
    console.log("POC Succesful",stringx)
}
```

Comment: you should use the [innerHtml] template binding. Why are you getting FE functions from the BE?

Comment: @JonasPraem anything provided in innerhtml doesn't get compiled from angular.

Comment: anybody who can answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use html compiler component https://www.npmjs.com/package/@codehint-ng/html-compiler.

With this you can store simple angular components event in database of somethind else.